# Issue in Do while statement that keeps looping itself

Tags: c, loops, char, scanf, do-while

I try to force the user to choose only Between R , C or T . But i made the statement and it keeps reasking me to reput an input as it tries to say that the given letter isn't one of them . Also to verify i tried to print hello but it doesn't get printed so that means the software is still stuck at do while statement . Any help ?
My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a;
    do 
    {
        printf ("Choisit parmis R , C ou T\n");
        scanf("%c", &a);
    } while (!((a == "R") ||(a == "T") ||(a == "C") ));
    printf("hey");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: enable compiler warnings. They will tell you exactly what is wrong here.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @bolov well sorry i didn't post them , From answers above , i was comparing strings to characters which is uncorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See there is a very small problem here. I am assuming you just learnt a language like python which confuses you. In C, Strings inside double quotes represent strings while inside single quotes represent char. Check this

```
var c = "C";//This is a string
var c = 'C';//This is a char
```

So you are comparing a string and char which will never be equal
As for you code, write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a;
    do 
    {
        printf ("Choisit parmis R , C ou T\n");
        scanf("%c", &a);
    } while (!((a == 'R') ||(a == 'T') ||(a == 'C') ));
    printf("hey");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it works give the answer an upvote and accept the answer by clicking the tick next to the answer and make it green

Comment: I will my friend

Comment: I am not upvoting this answer because `scanf` will match the newline character on the second function call, if the user enters a wrong character the first time. See Vlad's answer for a solution to this problem. If you edit your question to fix this, I will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

For starters use

```
scanf( " %c", &a );
       ^^^^^
```

instead of

```
scanf( "%c", &a );
       ^^^^
```

Otherwise the function will read also white spaces.

`"R"`, `"T"`, `"C"` are string literals that have the type `char[2]`. Used in expressions with rare exceptions they are converted to pointers to their first elements of the type `char *`.

So in fact you are trying to compare a character with pointers.

Instead of the string literals you have to use character ,literals `'R'`, `'T`, `'C'`

So the condition of the loop can look like

```
} while ( a != 'R' && a != 'T' && a != 'C' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the character a with the strings "R", "T" and "C", which is not what you want.  You want to compare against the single characters, which is written like this:

```
while (!((a == 'R') ||(a == 'T') ||(a == 'C') ));
```

Note that single quotes ' ' are used to write character constants.

Comment: "You are comparing the character a with the strings" -- This is not quite correct. The OP is comparing the character to the **pointers** to the strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate i really understood now i was a bit confused

Comment: This is not the only problem in the code. Please see the other two answers (and the comments thereof) for further information.